# interchange MySQL/MariaDB .frm files

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Is there any effect if i interchange MySQL/MariaDB .frm files from dbs with similar structure on any CRUD operation?

note: the different is some tables have different fields, whether its existence, datatype, default value or any others.

Answer (score 0):

The .frm drives the parsing of rows.  So if the datatype or number of columns changes, it seems very likely that the rows cannot be read.

Consider using a `VIEW` to "change" the structure of a table.